# flutter error when debug in android 5 device

Tags: flutter, flutter-android

I'm new in flutter,
I installed flutter, IDE, Android Studio and SDKs in my laptop win 10 recently,
Now When I want to test first default app in my android device, I always face with this error
"Launching lib\main.dart on SM N900 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
√  Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
Installing build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app.apk...
Error: ADB exited with exit code -1073741674

Error launching application on SM N900.
"

in addition I should say no problem exist after running flutter doctor

now I run flutter run --verbose
result:
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: try running `flutter run --verbose` in cmd and post the logs here

Comment: I did that and add 3 pictures to the question

Comment: try this build apk `flutter build apk && flutter install`

Comment: create a new project again. It says in the error that no pubspec.yaml is found